# Getting the latest value of the item in a column and displaying that value into other list, without using code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

[image]

I want to get the highlighted value, that is the latest value of the "Availed" from the list shown above, and display it on the second list's "Availed" column, circled below:

[image]

Basically, what I am trying to do is, whenever a new item is created in the second list, it fetches the latest value of the "Availed" from the first list and displays in its "Availed" column.

I have tried couple of lookups with IDs and dates using SharePoint designer 2013, but every time I am getting the first entry.

The only way, I could achieve this was, by mentioning the exact item ID in the lookup, but I do not want that. I want that it should automatically pick the latest value when a new item is created in the second list.

Also, there are couple of solutions online using the code, but I am not that great at coding and want to achieve this feature without coding.

Is there a way we can do this without a code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workflow for second list, in your workflow, call REST api by 'Call HTTP Web Service' action, [Sample here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/).

Use rest api to get the latest value by $orderby, [demo here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-selecting-filtering-sortin/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I will try this option.